# Creating Custom Twitter Application

Tags: objective-c, twitter

I am trying to create a custom twitter application. But, I am not getting how to create.

How can I do that?

Comment: That's pretty open ended... What would you like your application to do?

Comment: What is your question? be more specific? is it about c? or is it about twitter api?

Comment: If u see properly u will see twitter is single page interface made with hashbang / hasgtag, best example to start with hashtag is here http://www.amitpatil.me/create-gmail-like-app-using-html5-history-api-and-hashbang/

Answer (score 2):

Best place to start is here: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Or have a look at [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine)